# win32com: work with excel file by opening it in background

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

So I use following code to open an existing excel file. Even though I make visible to False, but this always open the excel file UI. However I want to run it in the background. How can I do that?

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('my_sheet.xlsm')
excel.Visible = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I now use one of MS Excel's alternative Kingsoft Spreadsheet. My snippet below used to run the application in the background.

```
from win32com import client

xApp = None
for aname in ('Excel', 'eT', 'KeT'):
    try:
        xApp = client.Dispatch(aname + '.Application')
    except client.pywintypes.com_error:
        continue
    else:
        break
if xApp is None:
    print('No app found')
    raise SystemExit    # Application is unavailable.
else:
    # do something
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('my_sheet.xlsm')
```

On older version of MS Excel (before 2013) and KS Spreadsheet (before 2014), the above code worked fine, even without explicitly setting xApp.Visible to False. However, on recent version of Spreadsheet, it would launch a small UI window when quitting the application.